# Segmentation fault when using dpbtrf

Tags: c++, lapack, scientific-computing, lapacke

I try to use the LAPACK routine `dpbtrf` ([Documentaton](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/dba/group__double_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_gad8b0e25cecc84ea3c5aa894ca1f1b5ca.html#gad8b0e25cecc84ea3c5aa894ca1f1b5ca)) in c++ but always get a segmentation fault. I am not sure how to pass the matrix `LAPACKE_dpbtrf` and tried to replicate it from the few examples I found without success. How to make the code below work?

I want to compute the cholesky decomposition of the matrix

```
   1 -0.9    0    0    0
-0.9 1.81 -0.9    0    0
   0 -0.9 1.81 -0.9    0
   0    0 -0.9 1.81 -0.9
   0    0    0 -0.9 1.81
```

Here is what I tried:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<lapacke.h>


int main() {
    lapack_int info;
    lapack_int N = 5;
    lapack_int KD = 1; 
    lapack_int LDAB = KD + 1;

    double AB[N * KD] = {
     1, 1.81, 1.81, 1.81, 1.81, 
     -0.9, -0.9, -0.9, -0.9, -0.9
    };


    info = LAPACKE_dpbtrf( LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, 'L', N, KD, AB, LDAB);


    for(int i=0;i<N * KD; i++)
   {
         std::cout << AB[i] << std::endl;

   }

    return(info);

}
```

Comment: `double AB[N * KD]` warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array. Don't rely on a compiler extension and use a pointer (with 'new') instead.

Comment: `double AB[N * KD];` -- Don't do this.  Do this: `std::vector<double> AB(N * KD);`.  This probably doesn't fix your issue, but at least your code is now C++ compliant.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `LAPACKE_dpbtrf` wants a `double *` See [src](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/db9/lapacke__dpbtrf_8c_source.html)

Comment: @Ripi2 -- A vector has a [data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) member function that provides the `double *` you're speaking of.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know. Just wanted you to point it out ;)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is this better or still bad? `std::vector<double> AB(N * LDAB);
AB = { 1, 1.81, 1.81, 1.81, 1.81, 
   -0.9, -0.9, -0.9, -0.9, -0.9 };`

Comment: @Alex -- You can initialize the vector in one statement: `std::vector<double> AB = { 1, 1.81, etc. };`.  If the vector has be resized to `N * LDAB` later on, then you can call `AB.resize(N * LDAB);` to expand the vector to accommodate the new entries.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the advice. I am a c++ newbie and every help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't have the proper dimensions for `AB`. According to the documentation, the size is (LDAB,N), not (KD,N).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this mistake. However, I still do not get the desired result.

Comment: You mean, it still crashes?

Comment: You may want to post a new question then, if it's not obvious like a row/column issue.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. But since the compile error is gone I can try to find the solution myself.